# nginx as reverse proxy for something like gmail ... what am I missing?

Tags: nginx, gmail, reverse-proxy

What started as a project to let a friend access her email from a network which blocked gmail access now has me intrigued by why it's hard.

I've set up a little nginx reverse proxy to try this, with the vhost configured like

```
server {
  server_name my.host.com;
  resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;
  location / {
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass https://mail.google.com/;
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
  location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
  }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.host.com/fullchain.pem; 
# managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.host.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = my.host.com) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
     } # managed by Certbot
  listen 80;
    server_name my.host.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

...I've gone through a few iterations, but what happens right now if you access `https://my.site.com` is you get redirected to `https://my.site.com/mail` with a 404 served from google saying "the requested url /mail/ was not found on this server"

So okay,  interesting, but I've iterated through a few things... having trouble with redirects to accounts.google.com, etc.

Now, I appreciate that I'm trying to circumvent someone's rules, but I'm also surprised that I couldn't find a clear obvious config for this (it seems like the sort of thing that's been solved several times).  And in any case I'd like to learn what I'm missing.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Google would most definitely have disallowed things that allow for any potential information leakage. By using proxy pass, you're essentially telling NGINX to pass some information (your request specifically) to Google, and crossing your fingers that they would accept it, and send you what you want back (which isn't happening).

You would have much better luck setting up a VPN/web proxy or using Gmail's APIs to create an application that your friend can access.